# How change CurrentJDK symbolic link in MacOS

Tags: java, macos, symlink

Currently in my Mac I have these JAVA versions:

---

MyMac$ cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

$ ls -la

total 0

drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  136 17 Oct 11:21 .

drwxrwxr-x  5 root  wheel  170 17 Oct 11:21 ..

drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 14 Jul 22:52 1.6.0.jdk

drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 17 Oct 11:16 jdk1.7.0_79.jdk

---

What I am trying to do is change the symbolic link to point to JDK 7 instead of JDK 6:

---

$cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions

$ls -la

drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 17 Oct 11:21 .

drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel  340 17 Oct 11:21 ..

lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 17 Oct 11:21 1.4 -> CurrentJDK

lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 17 Oct 11:21 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK

lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 17 Oct 11:21 1.5 -> CurrentJDK

lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 17 Oct 11:21 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK

lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 17 Oct 11:21 1.6 -> CurrentJDK

lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 17 Oct 11:21 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK

drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel  272 17 Oct 11:21 A

lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    1 17 Oct 11:21 Current -> A

lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   52 17 Oct 11:21 CurrentJDK -> 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents

---

Unfortunately I cannot remove the link. I am getting an operation not permitted error:

sudo rm CurrentJDK

rm: CurrentJDK: Operation not permitted

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El Capitan new feature: System Integrity Protection (SIP), was the cause of this problem. I had to disable SIP first.

Follow these steps to disable SIP:

Restart your Mac.
Before OS X starts up, hold down Command-R and keep it held down until you see an Apple icon and a progress bar. Release. This boots you into Recovery.
From the Utilities menu, select Terminal.
At the prompt type exactly the following and then press Return:

```
csrutil disable
```

Terminal should display a message that SIP was disabled.
From the apple menu, select Restart.
You can re-enable SIP by following the above steps, but using `csrutil enable` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running OS X 10.11 (El Capitan), there is a new feature called "Rootless" which prevents editing of files under /System/ except by installers and the like. You may be able to solve whatever problem is requiring you to update the CurrentJDK symlink just by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home

If you truly want to modify that /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK symlink, you will likely have have to disable Rootless mode. You could also try running the Java 7 installer again, though I'm not certain that this will work

More information on the Rootless feature can be found here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really

Answer (score 0):

Steps that worked on macOS Catalina 10.15.2 and RStudio 1.2.5036

## Install Java 11.0.1 from here (requires free account):

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase11-5116896.html

## Run javareconf

You probably need to run the command below, but RStudio seems not acknowledge the settings:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

## Remove (if installed) and reinstall rJava from source

```
remove.packages("rJava") 
install.packages("rJava", type="source", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com")
```

Installing rJava from source seems to run a different configuration setup that will look for Java and it will display "checking Java support in R" as part of the output that seems accepted by RStudio.

## Change ~/.Rprofile

This change to .Rprofile may also be necessary:

```
options(java.home="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home")
Sys.setenv(DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/")
```